# Security of a password-only login?

Tags: security

I'm working on an admin page in PHP in which a user system seems like overkill. I was thinking of just requiring one password to access the admin page, but I'm not sure if would be safe to do so. I can't see any specific security problems that this might pose, can anyone else think of any?

**Edit**: By "a user system is overkill" I meant that there is not likely to be more than one user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up what others have said: Fine as long as the password is not simple, but more vulnerable to brute-force attacks.

Solution: You can enforce a password-complexity policy, and you can throttle further login attempts - get it wrong once, next login is artificially slowed 4 seconds. Get it wrong again, 8 seconds, and so on.

Option: Use two fields - username and password - but make the user also just a static value, like the password. Twice the guessing, twice the effort, twice the security (and twice the hassle for users..)

You could actually throw in a CAPTCHA. That would thwart brute-force attacks pretty well.

Comment: +1 for the two fields idea. I once did something similar, except I just had two passwords (one static one and one that depends on the user).

Comment: Ugh! As mentioned in another answer, having twice the length of a password would buy you the same amount of security. And I hate how Ubuntu artificially makes me wait a few seconds because I've mistyped my password. You're just pissing legitamate users off. 3 strikes = captcha, 5 = 24 hour lock out sounds more reasonable to me.

Comment: Selected for getting past the math, and the CAPTCHA idea.

Comment: @Mark those few seconds are there to prevent timing attacks.

Comment: I really wish more systems did better throttling. It'd be great if Windows would be "wait 1 minute" instead of "You're locked out."

Answer (score 7):

Complexity of the passwords aside, there are two problems:

- The passwords must be unique now

If you have user+pass, users can have the same password. Under your model, they all must have a unique one.

- Limited tracability

A good reason for user accounts to see who does what. You remove this, a little, with a general password as you need to assume, again, a one-to-one matching between them, and users. This may or may not be an issue.

For some of my admin pages, I don't really have a "user" so much as I have two tokens that need to be entered (because I'm the only admin).

For general people signing up, though, and if the password is entered by them, this is not an appropriate plan. If it's just for your admin pages for you, and you generate passwords of an appropriate complexity, life will be good.

Comment: As I just edited in the question, the one admin is the only "user".

Answer (score 2):

It suffers from the same issues as a shared login, making it impossible to revoke for a specific user (if someone leaves, a users computer is compromised, etc), along with the issue of being *way* more open to brute force attacks (as mentioned by others).

For something simple, that doesn't seem to need a full fledged user/pass system, why not use HTTP Auth built into the server? Easy to setup, doesn't need to be shared, but would require *no* extra code on the admin script.

Comment: I'm using CodeIgniter which routes URL's, so I don't think that would work.

Comment: I got a couple of down-votes, guess that's because I only half addressed the question, and answered what you didn't ask, but seemed to be the root of it. I can't think of an easy way to implement plain old .htaccess style auth with a framework though.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problems if your admins wouldn't use simple passwords, like 1234567.

Answer (score 1):

I, have the opinion that having a single password makes the system MORE secure (not less), as long as both the password and system are secure.

The reason is that when you have several users, it just takes one of them with a bad password to be the "weak link in the chain"

That said, nothing wrong with it as long as essential security measures are in place - and keep in mind brute forcing is easier (so make sure it's impossible/ineffective)

Answer (score 0):

I would think that for your admin page (one would think the most secure page) that you would want very tight security?

If your "admin" user has a "hard to discover" username and that is paired with a very secure password I would think that this would be a better system.

Ideally I think you would want to have a complex username and password:

e.g.

```
Username: e4t_Gjw3@gp
Password: q!-gr7cBFL045$bd
```

*Update:* based on the comments I thought I would elaborate on why user+pass is more secure than a pass of "e4t_Gjw3@gpq!-gr7cBFL045$bd".

Having both a username and a password doesn't double the security, it does much more than that.

Pretend that usernames and passwords are both 3 characters (from A-Z) no case-sensitivity.

To guess a password, using brute force, you would need up to: 26x26x26 = 17,576 tries.

To guess just a username, same conditions: 26x26x26 = 17,576 tries.

**If** you had to guess both *but they didn't have to match* it would be 17,576x2 = 35,152.

However, if you have to guess the username AND find the matching password it is more like:

17,576 usernames * 17,576 passwords = **308,915,776**

Of course if you have up to 16 character usernames (using case-sensitivity, numbers, punctuation etc.) and the same for passwords, the number of possibilities is ***Insanely Huge*** and thus... secure.

*Update2:* I seem to have missed typing the key bit of info I was trying to relay in my update.  In most systems I've seen or built, the username and password fields have a size restriction built into the SQL columns of 32, or 40, or X characters. In the ones I've seen where there is just a pass column, the size isn't typically doubled to 64, or 80 chars.

Obviously the pass-only column, and set value can be doubled in length to account for the lack of username - but I have rarely if at all seen this done.

Comment: I was going to answer something similar to this, but I forgot to hit Post. +1

Comment: how would that be diferent from
> password: e4t_Gjw3@gpq!-gr7cBFL045$bd
?

Comment: Complex user/pw pairs make people write them down - not necessarily an issue, but could be. A long passphrase like "The letters X, Y and Z are first in the alphabet" is easier for users to remember, plus very secure due to length and included commas. It's also not easy to guess as long as you don't make it too obvious (ie. use your brain)

Comment: could you explain how is that different from a password 'e4t_Gjw3@gpq!-gr7cBFL045$bd' ?

Comment: with user+password the amount of tries to get the correct is exponential to power of two, with just one field it's not.

Comment: @Jani Hartikainen - the tries to get the password right is numChars^charsetCount. having a username/password combination or a longer password (by the same chars) is , doing the maths - the same.

Comment: @jcinacio I've updated my answer to explain how 2 values is always more difficult than one value

Comment: I was thinking it doubled as well. That seals it for me, thanks.

Comment: The only issue I think is, won't 90% of end-users choose "admin" as the admin account name? Is guessing an admin's account name ever really that difficult?

Comment: -1 because even after the edit, you're still missing the point.  The security provided by a 32-character password is exactly the same as that provided by a 16 char username and 16 char password.

Comment: Using a separate user name and password provides the same security as a combined user name and password of equal length. If it is possible to determine if the user name or password is wrong, using a separate user name and password is extremely much weaker then the combined user name and password.

Comment: I would also like to comment on usernames and security. usernames have nothing to do with security - they are meant to, well, identify users. if you need more security using passwords just use stronger passwords and a secure system.

Comment: Size of alphabet (a). Separate user name (n) and password (m): a^n * a^m = a^(n + m). Combined user name and password: a^(n + m). Separate user name and password with information about the wrong part: a^n + a^m <= a^min(n+1,m+1)

Comment: And here I thought I was asking a programming question, not a math question. :P

Comment: Deselected as the answer because I think that you should _assume_ that the attacker knows the user name anyway.

Comment: @Ortzinator - if the attacker does know the user name, then yes a user+pass field will get you no additional security, in fact it will be significantly less.  Thus I, and many others would not suggest that you use "admin", "administrator" etc. as the username.  As a few have pointed out, a big password that is the length of the username and the password combined would create the same number of possible tests, however in most cases I've seen, if a single password (and no username) is required, the length of the password is not increased to account for the lack of username.

Comment: -1 for faulty assumptions.  To get the most secure password focus on password security.  Breaking a password into multiple fields won't make a different.

Answer (score 0):

As Jake said, there are many reasons not to do this but it depends on what your application is doing.  You need to do enough to put amateur hackers off.  Make sure the admin use a strong password - 10 digits, with at least one capital and one symbol or something like that.

Most security experts would still frown on this though.

Answer (score 0):

Password only + Captcha is ideal, Captcha would automatically implement rate-limiting and a strong password will make it secure.